# Creating a chart with network use in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, charts

I'm looking to create a chart with the history of network usage in my company. The DBA already guaranteed that the data exists and will create a query to get the data from the DB and then I can manipulate that info.

I never created a chart before in Asp.Net, so I really don´t know how to begin, and the samples that I found on the internet, using Microsoft Chart Control where really not clear to a beginner and they were well outdated.

I´m looking for a way to create that chart and populate it with my variables.

I don´t have the query yet and the Microsoft Chart Control Add On can´t be installed in Visual Studio 2013, so I have nothing yet.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I can´t use Highcharts because it´s not freeware.

Answer (score 0):

You may read the database from your query into array variables, then use those variables to plot the chart. The following is based on a charting library called [ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com).

```
//Open the connection to your database (using MS SQL as an example)
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)

//Issue the SQL query to read the data
string queryString = "SELECT MyTimeStamp, MyNetworkUsage FROM XXX;";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

//Convert to arrays
ChartDirector.DBTable table = new ChartDirector.DBTable(reader);
DateTime[] timeStamps = table.getColAsDateTime(0);  //1st column is timestamp
double[] data = table.getCol(1);  //2nd column is data
```

Now you can simply use those arrays in any charting example that accepts arrays as data. Some examples are:

[A simple .NET line chart](http://www.advsofteng.com/doc/cdnet.htm#multiline2.htm)

[A .NET line chart with tracking cursor](http://www.advsofteng.com/doc/cdnet.htm#tracklabelweb.htm)